# Why Bootstrap-5 row and usual div blocks have a different width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

So I have very simple code like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="pt-5  bg-info">
  <!-- Something -->
</div>

<div class="row pt-4 bg-success">
  <!-- Something -->
</div>
```

[image]

But, as a result (of this particular code), I have 2 these blocks with different width. So why it is happened and how to prevent such situations?

Comment: Why do you expect to have the same result with different classes?

Comment: Rows are expected to be used with columns (and containers). Please review the Bootstrap docs so you understand the grid system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Bootstrap library's internal `row` class `-bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;` to set the property. If you manually overwrite this property, this behavior will be resolved as you wish. Changing the library's behavior in this way causes different side effects. This is not recommended behavior. That's why I suggest you follow the steps in section "Suggestion".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .row {
        --bs-gutter-x: 0rem !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pt-5  bg-info"></div>
    <div class="row pt-4 bg-success"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

### Suggestion

The `pt` class is used to change the `padding-top` property. The different use of the `pt` class is not relevant to the problem. To responsively place elements horizontally, define child `<div>` elements with `row` class within a `<div>` element with `container` class.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pt-5 bg-info"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pt-4 bg-success">
  </div>
</div>
```

### References

- [Bootstrap v5.2. - Gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters/)
- [Bootstrap v5.2 - Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/)